# All the files created have executable permission after doing some alterations to fstab

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab

I made the following changes in /etc/fstab, after doing this any file i create in any of the partitions has executable permission.

Pls help me out.

This is my /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
  proc                                       /proc        proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid                 0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
  UUID=89e6ce75-1460-4c7e-ab26-ada11484cf4e  /            ext4  errors=remount-ro                  0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda11 during installation
  UUID=fb568186-5d39-4a60-9412-c254a0489490  none         swap  sw                                 0  0  

  UUID=905848155847F90C   /media/EDUCATIONAL      ntfs-3g    defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,umask=007  0  0 
  UUID=CEB008F2B008E337   /media/ENTERTAINMENT    ntfs-3g    defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,umask=007  0  0  
  UUID=7216C6C016C68517   /media/PROJECTS         ntfs-3g    defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,umask=007  0  0
```

and when I list my files, I see that all have executable permissions.

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 manu users 1213 Apr 20 20:28 message_receive.c
-rwxrwx--- 1 manu users 1111 Apr 19 16:02 message_send.c
-rwxrwx--- 1 manu users 1110 Apr 19 16:06 message_sender1.c
-rwxrwx--- 1 manu users 1110 Apr 19 16:06 message_sender2.c
-rwxrwx--- 1 manu users 1111 Apr 19 16:07 message_sender3.c
-rwxrwx--- 1 manu users 7442 Apr 20 20:41 receiver
```

I want permissions like this

```
-rw------- 1 manu manu 1213 Apr 20 20:28 message_receive.c
-rw------- 1 manu manu 1111 Apr 19 16:02 message_send.c
-rw------- 1 manu manu 1110 Apr 19 16:06 message_sender1.c
-rw------- 1 manu manu 1110 Apr 19 16:06 message_sender2.c
-rw------- 1 manu manu 1111 Apr 19 16:07 message_sender3.c
-rwx------ 1 manu manu 7442 Apr 20 20:41 receiver
```

I want the above permissions what changes should I make the in the fstab?

all the above files are created in /media/PROJECTS. Here all the files I create had executable permission, I don't want that to happen only the executable files should have executable permission.